# Crystal Report Error Failed to enable constraints

Tags: c#, .net

```
View_Atten_One_By_One mydataset1 = new View_Atten_One_By_One();

                    View_Atten_One_By_OneTableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter nfdAdapter1 = new View_Atten_One_By_OneTableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter();
                    nfdAdapter1.Fillattenbyemp(mydataset1.DataTable1, txtEmpId.Text);

                    ViewAttenByEmp nfpbdel1 = new ViewAttenByEmp();
                    nfpbdel1.SetDataSource(mydataset1);
                    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = nfpbdel1;
```

Error

Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Exception Throws in this code segment

nfdAdapter1.Fillattenbyemp(mydataset1.DataTable1, txtEmpId.Text);

Answer (score 0):

If This kind of error happen remove the Primary key in the DataSet